# BroadcastReceiver Not receiving Broadcast

Tags: android

I am trying to broadcast a toast message with the following code extending `Activity`. But the broadcast is not received by another `Activity`, the toast is not displayed. Can someone solve my error? The main activity is **SendBroadcast.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class SendBroadcast extends Activity {

    public static String BROADCAST_ACTION =
                             "com.unitedcoders.android.broadcasttest.SHOWTOAST";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void sendBroadcast(View v) {
        Intent broadcast = new Intent();
        broadcast.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        sendBroadcast(broadcast);
    }
}
```

Toast Display Activity is **ToastDisplay.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ToastDisplay extends Activity {

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(SendBroadcast.BROADCAST_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

and **manifest.xml** is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.broad"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SendBroadcast"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".ToastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.unitedcoders.android.broadcasttest.SHOWTOAST" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There can be two types of broacast: static and dynamic. Static are those that are declared in the manifest file. Dynamic can be declared during runtime. You combined these two types of broadcast in one broadcast.

To declare a simple dynamic broadcast you can use the following code (that is based on your code). It will simply display toast message when activity is shown.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BroadcastTestActivity extends Activity {

    public static String BROADCAST_ACTION =     
                            "com.unitedcoders.android.broadcasttest.SHOWTOAST";
    BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.w("Check", "Inside On Receiver");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        registerReceiver(br, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sendBroadcast();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(br);
    }

    public void sendBroadcast() {
        Intent broadcast = new Intent();
        broadcast.setAction(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        broadcast.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        sendBroadcast(broadcast);
    }
}
```

So now instead of showing toast you can call your new activity. The following actions depend  on your needs (what you want to do).

Comment: ok brother can u tell me i have to remove that static broadcast from manifest and can u give me a hint what will be my rest of .java files

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. I've showed you a very simple example how to show a toast message that is shown after broadcast has been received. You can simply create a new project and test this class.

Comment: first of all simpley i want to display TOast dynamically

Comment: The code I've proposed is showing toast after the start of the application. Simply copy this code to a new project and it will show you a toast.

Comment: i did this and problem is solved                                          @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
     //   unregisterReceiver(br);
       sendBroadcast(); 
    }

Answer (score 3):

Where is `ToastReceiver` class?

```
<receiver android:name=".ToastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.unitedcoders.android.broadcasttest.SHOWTOAST"/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>`
```

Change

```
public class ToastDisplay extends Activity {
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

}
```

to

```
public class ToastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<activity android:name=".SendBroadcast" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BROADCAST" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In `onCreate()` call

```
sendBroadcast(v);
```

Comment: What is the ` <action android:name="android.intent.action.BROADCAST" ` for?  Doesn't see like this would be necessary...

Comment: I think it's for testing - sendBroadcast would (hopefully) trigger the broadcastReciever

Answer (score -2):

```
Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        try {
            String RESULT = new TestAsyncTask().execute(" ").get();
            System.out.println("RESULT "+RESULT);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```